# Is there any varargs array construction method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, verbosity

There's the very useful `Arrays.asList()`:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

But there's no `Arrays.array()`:

```
public static <T> T[] array(T... values) {
    return values;
}
```

While being absolutely trivial, this would be a quite handy way of constructing arrays:

```
String[] strings1 = array("1", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8");

// as opposed to the slightly more verbose
String[] strings2 = new String[] { "1", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8" };

// Of course, you can assign array literals like this
String[] strings3 = { "1", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8" };

// But you can't pass array literals to methods:
void x(String[] args);

// doesn't work
x({ "1", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8" });

// this would
x(array("1", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8"));
```

Is there such a method anywhere else in the Java language, outside of `java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: Lukas, you can always request that method in Arrays. :) OpenJDK is, well, an open project. ;) Submit patch, and see if they will accept it. I believe there is use for a method like your `array()`.

Comment: @DejanLekic, that's a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could see [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org). You must use lib version 3.0 or higher.

Examples:

```
String[] array = ArrayUtils.toArray("1", "2");
String[] emptyArray = ArrayUtils.<String>toArray();
```

Comment: +1 I added an example to this good answer. It is not visible until it is peer reviewed.

Comment: @dogbane toPrimitive and toObject for example, they do not the same things, but nearly :)

Comment: @Fatal ah, `toArray` is in commons.lang 3! I'll update the links.

Comment: I guess that's as good as it gets right now... Time to upgrade commons-lang, soon :-)

Comment: -1: That is actually longer that using the built-in `new String[] {"1", "2"}`

Comment: @Peter Lawrey From Apache's javadoc: "The method is typically used in scenarios, where the caller itself uses generic types that have to be combined into an array."

Comment: @Fatal Which is the second, longer syntax in the example above which cannot be staticly imported.

Comment: @LukasEder, So you are adding a library method to save perhaps 5 characters of code. If you use the second form, as suggested its always going to longer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That's 5 characters for every one of my next 5000 method invocations in methods with nasty signature like `xxx(String[], Object[], String[])`. Whatever makes my life easier, I'll gladly take

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need for `array()` method in Java in my opinion. If you want less verbose as you said you can use literals. Or in method parameters you can use varargs (no need for array at all). Based on your title this is what you want to do. You can just do this:

```
public static void doThings(String... values) {
    System.out.println(values[0]);
}

doThings("This", "needs", "no", "array");
```

Only if method signature actually has an array you will have to specify the `new String[]`, which is not too much extra writing in my opinion.

**Edit:** It seems that you do want less verbose way to call methods with arrays as parameters. I wouldn't add external library just of method of one line. This would work for example:

```
public static <T> T[] toArr(T... values) {
    return values;
}

yourMethod(toArr("1", "2", "3"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have many methods of this type: `xx(String a, String[] b, Object[] c)`. And I can't change those...

Comment: Ok, then I don't know any method that is less verbose in Java. Btw, `varargs` in Java typically refer to the `Object...` style method parameter. Maybe you should change the title.

Comment: Why change the title? I'm looking for a method with that signature `<T> T[] xx(T...)`... Looks like a "varargs array construction" method. I want to construct arrays using a varargs parameter...

Comment: @LukasEder I thought you wanted to construct varargs or something (it's not that clear). I added method as an example to the answer.

Comment: Yep. Just like in commons-lang 3.0 `ArrayUtils`... I guess, I'll have to upgrade my commons-lang, some time soon. Btw, I tagged the question with [tag:verbosity]

Answer (score 1):

ArrayUtils from Apache Commons Lang (v3.0 or higher):

```
String[] array = ArrayUtils.toArray("1", "2");
String[] emptyArray = ArrayUtils.<String>toArray();
```

... or just take the code from Apache and implement "yourself":

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(final T... items) {
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something shorter than

```
x(new String[] {"1", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8"});
```

I use the following which is shorter than the list by itself.

```
   x("1,1,2,3,5,8".split(","));
// {"1", "1", "2", "3", "5", "8"}
```

It doesn't use any additional library.

---

Say you want keys and values you can still use varargs

```
public static <K,V> Map<K, V> asMap(K k, V v, Object ... keysAndValues) {
    Map<K,V> map = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    map.put(k, v);
    for(int i=0;i<keysAndValues.length;i+=2)
        map.put((K) keysAndValues[i], (V) keysAndValues[i+1]);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: ;-) OK, but that was just an example. Of course, I want to be able to pass variables / constants as well...

Comment: A variable length array of objects of any type. Doesn't sound very OO. ;)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any OO-related problem with that... It's exactly the same as `<T> List<T> Arrays.asList(T...)`. To me at least...

Comment: Except `T` is one specific type, like String or Integer.

Comment: Ehm, yes...? Isn't that nice? `Integer[] i = array(1, 2, 3)` and `String[] s = array("1", "2", "3")` and even `Object[] o = array(1, "2", 3.0)`. I don't miss Java 1.4 :-)

Comment: Not as nice as `Integer[] i = {1,2,3}`, `String[] s = "1,2,3".split(",")` and `Object[] o = { 1, "2", 3.0 }`  The later example suggests you have problem with your design IMHO as there is nothing to stop you passing `{ "3", 2.0, 1 }`

Comment: Peter, Peter, Peter... ;-) I can't pass array literals to methods, e.g. `x({1,2,3})`... I do have to live with calling methods like `xyz(String[], Object[], String[])`. And because I cannot change those methods, I wanted to at least change my invoking those methods.

Comment: So I would use a helper method like `public static <T> T[] a(T... ts) { return ts; }` It won't be any shorter. (or even use `$(1,2,3)` or `_(1,2,3)` ;)